# It's possible to share data-section (veriables) between twice `dlopen`ed sahrdLib in the same process?

Tags: c, dlopen

On linux platform, if a sharedLib are opened tiwce with **dlopen** **in the same process**, are the data-section(variables) located in the same mem-address or not?

I want to initialize a global var in the shardLib on first dlopen, and use it (by dlsym) with the second dlopen, is it possiable?

```
void* hdl0 = dlopen("foo.so");
void* varPtr = dlsym(hdl0, "var_name");
*varPtr = INIT_VALUE;

void* hdl1 = dlopen("foo.so");
void* varPtr = dlsym(hdl1, "var_name");
// I expect the var has value 'INIT_VALUE' here
```

Comment: Thanks for you anwser! I've read this anwser, it says "at the second dlopen ,the os dose not have to load the **read-only** data from the disk",  dose this mean that the `.data `  and `.bass` section will be reloaded?   Actually I've write a programm to test this, which shows the varPtr point to different address. Is it possiable that I've missed something in using `dlopen`? @a3f

Comment: "Actually I've written a program to test this, which shows the varPtr point to different address." -- that's unlikely; you are probably making some mistake or misinterpreting what you actually observe. You can ask a new question, showing your _entire_ test program and the observations you make which lead you to think you are observing different addresses.